# Sending touch events from view to controller

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have custom UIView that is being displayed in controller's view. I need to display a view controller modally when something in that custom view is tapped. What is the most efficient way to notify the view controller (if it exists) about the touch from the custom view's touchesBegan()?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Declare `UITapGestureRecognizer` like this and add gesture recognizer to your custom view

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.tapOnCustomView(_:)))
customView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Now receive the tap

```
func tapOnCustomView(tap:UITapGestureRecognizer){
  // present your targeted view controller modally      
}
```

NB: UITapGestureRecognizer allocation syntax vary with Swift version. This one is for Swift 2.2